# Why 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign'?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.random.randn(10), 
               'b' : np.random.randn(10), 
               'c' : np.random.randn(10)})
log_sum = np.log(np.abs(df["a"] + df['b'] + df['c']))
print log_sum
df.assign(log_sum=log_sum)
df.head()
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign'

Comment: Is the statement "New in version 0.16.0." relevant?

Comment: And you can always easily do `df['log_sum] = log_sum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be using older version of Pandas,

**assign** method is introduced in Version 0.16.0, [doc ref](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

you can check your pandas version using

```
import pandas
pandas.__version__
```

upgrade pandas-

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```