# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign'

Tags: python, pandas

While assign a new column to my DataFrame I get this error here is my code

```
def check_header(header, df):
    print("Header : ",header)
    for item in header:
        if not item in df.columns:
            df = df.assign(item) #here I'm getting error
    return df[header]
```

I have check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959637/why-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-assign) but din't work for me because my pandas version is satisfying it's

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.1.5'
```

what is problem in my code please help me.

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need add new columns by `header` list with convert not matched values to new columns filled by `NaN`s use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandawheres.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"test":["mkt1","mkt2","mkt3"],
                         "test2":["cty1","cty2","cty3"]})


def check_header(header, df):
    return df.reindex(header, axis=1)

a = ['test','test1','test3']
print (check_header(a, df))
   test  test1  test3
0  mkt1    NaN    NaN
1  mkt2    NaN    NaN
2  mkt3    NaN    NaN
```

If need same values in new columns use `fill_value` parameter:

```
def check_header(header, df):
    return df.reindex(header, axis=1, fill_value=0)

a = ['test','test1','test3']
print (check_header(a, df))
   test  test1  test3
0  mkt1      0      0
1  mkt2      0      0
2  mkt3      0      0
```

If need different values per new column use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with dictionary for new columns names like keys::

```
def check_header(header, df):
    diff = np.setdiff1d(header, df.columns)
    d = dict(zip(diff, diff))
    print (d)
    {'test1': 'test1', 'test3': 'test3'}
    
    return df.assign(**d).reindex(header, axis=1)

a = ['test','test1','test3']
print (check_header(a, df))
   test  test1  test3
0  mkt1  test1  test3
1  mkt2  test1  test3
2  mkt3  test1  test3
```

Comment: Hello @jezrael when I try this in my test file it was working fine but I add the same code in my original file it's giving me this error ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reindex'```

Comment: @AnkitTiwari - code is same, pandas version is same, header is list?

Comment: Yes header is a list and all other things are correct

Comment: @AnkitTiwari - So it is data related problem? If use in real code sample data working, if use real data raise error?

Comment: Hello @jezrael Thanks again ❤️️❤️️ problem was in my code I was calling a function where I'm not created a data frame that's why I was getting that error